# List of object to string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I want to convert the list of objects to string for the call to my API?

It's working for `data` array. but got an error for `data2` array

**Error** `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

```
let data = ["123","1234"]

let data2 = [NotificationModel(version: "2", bigPicture: "data"),
                 NotificationModel(version: "3", bigPicture: "data")]

struct NotificationModel: Codable {
    var version : String?
    var bigPicture : String?
}

func json(from object:Any) -> String? {
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}

    print("\(json(from:data2 as [NotificationModel]))")
    print("\(json(from: data as Any))")
```

Result should be looks like this

```
"notifications":"[{\"body\":\"dfg\",\"groupKey\":\"bhanukacom072\",\"messageData\":\"{\\\"audioSeconds\\\":0,\\\"chatCount\\\":891,\\\"chatFieldId\\\":\\\"16184658508585169\\\",\\\"content\\\":\\\"dfg\\\",\\\"createdAt\\\":{\\\"_seconds\\\":1621765164,\\\"_nanoseconds\\\":964804000},\\\"fromUserId\\\":\\\"W6qfPNooEwhRU3xVlF3FZYdxGeZ2\\\",\\\"fromUserName\\\":\\\"bhanuka com 072\\\",\\\"isChat\\\":true,\\\"messageStatus\\\":\\\"U\\\",\\\"readStatus\\\":\\\"U\\\",\\\"requirementId\\\":\\\"671\\\",\\\"sendBy\\\":\\\"V\\\",\\\"timestamp\\\":1621765164964,\\\"toUserId\\\":\\\"TVhRuzRekqnPhhmb1oATXwc10En62\\\",\\\"toUserName\\\":\\\"bhanuka yc\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"text\\\",\\\"unReadMessageCount\\\":4,\\\"version\\\":2,\\\"docId\\\":\\\"eIfo9thTzyUmURMGX2uyj\\\"}\",\"title\":\"You have a message from bhanuka com 072\",\"version\":\"2\"}]","isVendor":false},"executionTime":0.008731000125408173,"log":"Initial response","endpoint":"createChat"}
```

Comment: You can't transform `NotificationModel` into JSON String with `JSONSerialization`, you need `JSONEncoder`. And you should post the full error message where it should say so.

Comment: You want JSON Stringified within JSON? You don't have a Codable struct with `endpoint`, `log`?

Comment: no this is my android app log. I need samething on ios

Comment: What you expect is unclear. Clarify it.

Comment: @Larme sorry for my ugly English. my English is very bad. I expecting this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67683807/8822337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the thing you're trying to Encode conforms to the Encodable protocol. You can use Foundation's `JSONEncoder` plus a litle bit of generics to ensure that the input to your `json` function is encodable, like this:

```
import Foundation

let data = ["123","1234"]

let data2 = [NotificationModel(version: "2", bigPicture: "data"),
                 NotificationModel(version: "3", bigPicture: "data")]

struct NotificationModel: Codable {
    var version : String?
    var bigPicture : String?
}

func json<T:Encodable>(from object:T) -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(object)
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}

print("\(json(from: data2))")
print("\(json(from: data))")
```

Comment: can you recheck my question? I add my expectation

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting all that extra data from, but this approach will give you the encoding of whatever you put into the json function as a string, so whatever properties you put in your NotificationModel will be outputted in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a simple array of strings, which also is a valid json object.
But `data2` is an array of `Codable`s. Which by default is not a valid json object yet. You need to convert your `data2: [NotificationModel]` to `data2Json: [[String:Any]]` to make it a valid object first, and then pass it to your `json(from object` function. You should use `JSONEncoder` to encode the `[NotificationModel]` to a valid json object.

Comment: okay. But result is not string type right?

Comment: can you recheck my question? I add my expectation